# Trouble with javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code:

```
function f_dialogOpen()
{
    var e_window = document.createElement("div");
    e_window.style.position = 'absolute';
    var n_width  = 300;
    var n_height = 200;
    var a_docSize = f_documentSize();
    e_window.style.left = ((a_docSize[0] - n_width)  / 2) + a_docSize[2]) + 'px';
    e_window.style.top  = ((a_docSize[1] - n_height) / 2) + a_docSize[3]) + 'px';
    e_window.style.zIndex = 1002;

    e_window.innerHTML = 'Hello, world!';

    document.body.appendChild(e_window);
}
```

Function f_documentSize() returns array[4] with widnow size. Here is what I get using firebug:

```
missing ; before statement
e_window.style.left = ((a_docSize[0] - n_width) / 2) + a_docSize[2]) + 'px';\n
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong number of brackets:

```
e_window.style.left = ((a_docSize[0] - n_width)  / 2) + a_docSize[2]) + 'px';
e_window.style.top  = ((a_docSize[1] - n_height) / 2) + a_docSize[3]) + 'px';
```

You need:

```
e_window.style.left = (((a_docSize[0] - n_width)  / 2) + a_docSize[2]) + 'px';
e_window.style.top  = (((a_docSize[1] - n_height) / 2) + a_docSize[3]) + 'px';
```

Comment: actually he may need 3, or it could concatenate instead of add.